# How to multiply values within a nested array...times values in an another array (in Google Sheets)?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sumifs

This is hard to explain so my title sucks, and is just my best guess at how I might be able to approach this.  I have a Google Sheet of sales data for cases of various bottle sizes of kombucha. Column E is the sale date, Column G contains the item code, and column J is the quantity sold of said cases. See my (vastly simplified) sample data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17-LzGrNJtBr-FwOZtdaoCws3ayeGOHu_TdtGOfXj4cA/edit?usp=sharing

See my current test code below (also present in the Formula tab of the linked spreadsheet). It successfully gives me the combined number of cases sold of half-liter bottles and Growlers. The values in E4 and E5 are cells containing my start and end dates, respectively, so I'm constraining the results only to those which fall within a certain date range.

This code works, but now I need to figure out a way to sum the total number of bottles sold instead of # of cases. The data set is already massive and pushing the limits of google sheets, so adding a column to the source data sheet with # of bottles per case is not an option. Half liter cases hold 13 bottles, and growlers hold 5. Is there any way to do this with my current approach, using another array perhaps? Or any other approach that keeps the formula as simple as possible?

FYI the current formula is a proof of concept and I will be adding many additional types of cases to the existing formula, each containing a different number of bottles per case, and using it as part of a larger dynamic formula that allows you to switch between showing # cases vs # bottles vs # of actual liters sold, so this is why I am hoping to find an array-based approach that will let me do this without needing to resort to an absurdly long and complex formula of nested IF statements.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((XeroInvoiceData!$E$3:$E>=B4)*(XeroInvoiceData!$E$3:$E<=B5)), (--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(XeroInvoiceData!$G$3:$G, {"HalfLiterCase","GrowlerCase"}, 0)))), XeroInvoiceData!$J$3:$J)
```

I would be eternally grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ig0krumJu4Lj9-nIKJyRfPLTYbU-mzOL0JokRUDEqNc/edit?usp=sharing

My idea was to filter your table on date and sum by the type of container.
I wanted also to allow new types of containers that contain smaller units (bottles or liters).

[image]

I divided this job into 3 stages.

First we have to filter this table according to selected dates and container types.
I prepared a list that may be extended (all you need is to extend the filter range).

[image]

Then I have to vlookup values of units in each container and I try to do it inside the same formula.
General idea is

```
={[query results],arrayformula(ifna(vlookup([first column of query],$C$21:$D$26,2,0)*[second column of query])}
```

I divide it into 2 stages.
First stage referrs to query results in adjacent table:

[image]

Second stage uses indexes of query so formula is quite long:

[image]

Tell me if it solves your problem.